# c++ Using boost test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

How can I convert the following code to use boost unit test framework:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "graph.hh"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  const char* ifile = argv[1];

  Graph gp;
  gp.read_xml(ifile);

  std::cout << "Checking number of nodes and edges..."  << std::endl;
  int nodes_expected = 16;
  if(nodes_expected != gp.nodes()) {
    std::cout << "Test Failed." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Expected: " << nodes_expected << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result: " << gp.nodes() << std::endl;
  }
  int edges_expected = 15;
  if(edges_expected != gp.edges()) {
    std::cout << "Test Failed." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Expected: " << edges_expected << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result: " << gp.edges() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've read the documentation at ([Boost Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html)), but it doesn't tell me how to ingest arguments from the command line.  Otherwise, I could probably use BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL.

Comment: Wouldn't your test be specific to some special `ifile`? If yes there would be little need to change it later and you could just hardcode a path.

Comment: Tests should be fully self-contained, and this is no longer the case if you need to provide parameters to it. If you need to test with different files, then write a method doTest(string filename) and create several test cases which call this method with different hard-coded arguments. This way every other user of your codebase or a continous integration tool will be able to run all the tests without special knowledge about how to do that. Every other thing does not sound like a unit test to me.

Comment: There are general features that all `ifiles` contain.  I'm trying to create a test suite to test for those features.  Other test suites are more specific and I have hard-coded values for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include "graph.hh"
using namespace boost::unit_test;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_num_of_nodes )
{
  Graph gp;
  gp.read_xml( framework::master_test_suite().argv[1] );

  BOOST_MESSAGE( "Checking number of nodes and edges..." );

  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(16, gp.nodes());
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(15, gp.edges());
}
```

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for, however, now I'm having problems with boost and tinyxml.  My read_xml function uses tinyxml and it seems to be running some demo.xml instead of the file I'm passing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to embed `ifile` with a program like xxd(check out the -include option), see http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html.

That will give you a file with a char array that you can just #include in.

Comment: ifile? Why does including something as char-arrays help?

Comment: @phresnel It would avoid the whole issue of having to load a file at runtime.  This would make the test more self contained as well.

Comment: I see; you were referring to a variable name. Better use `this style` if you quote code ;) (downvote removed)

Answer (score 1):

In the boost unit test suite, you don't create a simple program the way you're describing.  You don't write test tools, you write test suites, built up from many functions (one per test case).  Those functions don't take arguments from the command line.

The test case functions you write will be one of:

- Nullary functions (no arguments)
- Unary functions (one argument)
- Built against a template class (to provide template arguments)

So, you'll want to either parse your arguments from a separate hard-coded file path (write the arguments to that 2nd file instead of passing them on the command line), and pass those to a unary-function test case, or simply give up and hard-code your file paths to your test suite, potentially one file per test case (function).

Unit test suites are designed this way so that they can be run in either the standard test runner, or an arbitrary runner, which will probably take its own command line parameters, and would require special care to support custom command line parameters.

The test runner gives you a lot of pluggable flexibility for your future needs (standardized test running, filtering, logging, etc), but you'll have to give up some program-like flexibility to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Custom command line arguments which was added in Boost::test like

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE runtime_configuration1
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
using namespace boost::unit_test;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_accessing_command_line)
{
    BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE( framework::master_test_suite().argc == 3 );
    BOOST_TEST( framework::master_test_suite().argv[1] == "--specific-param" );
    BOOST_TEST( framework::master_test_suite().argv[2] == "'additional value with quotes'" );
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( "'argv[0]' contains " << framework::master_test_suite().argv[0] );
}
```

From https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/custom_command_line_arguments.html